# What *is* a non-constructive comment, if this isn't?

Tags: discussion, support, comment, flagging, specific-flag

Today, in a now-deleted meta thread, I got the following comment (literal quote):

> @Lord_Farin baby

as a reply to a comment of mine. (Seconds later, the thread was deleted.)

I flagged this comment as "not constructive". My flag was declined.

I would appreciate an explanation as to what exactly the "constructive" content of this comment is. Perhaps it was edited within the grace period to something else? (I can't view the comment any more, so I can't check it myself.)

Comment: I think that the order of events may have had an influence.  The post itself was deleted before the flag was handled, and it is possible that the moderator in question simply decided not to delete a comment from an already deleted post.  (Interestingly, you apparently even _raised_ the flag after the post was deleted.)

Comment: @Arthur That's of course possible, but it strikes me as strange to not delete because it's a comment on a deleted thread. If one of two options has to be chosen, I'd suggest picking the one that doesn't require follow-up action if any of the circumstances happen to change (e.g. if OP undeletes their question).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: it is not that easy for an OP to undelete a question. (Non moderators generally have a difficult time finding their own deleted questions, since they do not show up on the question list!)

Comment: @WillieWong There [used to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491) a way to find own deleted questions, but I now see (from recent comment in that thread) that in may be gone. SE giveth and SE taketh away.

Comment: @user103254 Interesting. At least on main, that feature still exists (it also goes back further than the alluded 60 days for me).

Comment: @Lord_Farin SE implements changes on meta.SO before going network-wide, so it's possible that the feature is on its way out.

Comment: Don't worry, I have also been called a baby.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Arthur Fischer said, I declined the flag because the post was already deleted. That is because:

1. The post is already deleted, so the comment can no longer be seen by users with <10K reputation.
2. In such a case, I prefer to keep questionable comments visible to make it easier for making future moderation decisions.
3. Unfortunately there is no "do nothing and dismiss" button for comment flags.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the explanation.